# Import libraries to project

Tags: android, xmpp

I found this tutorial http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat-messenger-app-similar-to-whatsapp-using-xmpp-smack-4-1-api-from-scratch-part-2/ which is about creating chat application. So, in the begging  author say that we got to import some "third party libraries"(XMPP libraries, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2iPPSXcpjrGYmkwODRzT3FzOGM/view). The problem is that I don't have any idea how to do this. Can somebody help me with this? Forgot to mention that I put all files into my project but this is how they look(talking about icons)
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best way to add a library dependency is to go to: "File" -> "Project Structure..." then under "Modules" click on "app", lastly on the tabs up top click on "Dependencies"

On the screen that shows click on the plus (+) sign at the bottom a search will be prompted enter the library you want (i.e. GSON or jxmpp), click "OK" and that is it! you added the library.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your directory should look like this:

[image]

After you have the JAR files in the `libs` folder you can right click them and add them to the build path.

Comment: You have the "libraries" folder expanded but you should be using the "libs" folder. What's in the "libs" folder?

Comment: You also extracted the `org.zip` file to your app directory, not your src directory. The Smack API and GSON library files go in the `libs` folder, while the source code in the `org.zip` file should be extracted to your `src` directory.